# Unexpected result from multiplication of singles(floats) in c#

Tags: c#, floating-point, integer, expression

```
Single singleVal = 0.9f;
int u = (int)(singleVal * 10.0f); # u = 8
```

I know this is probably a dumb error but I cant figure out why result of the above expression is 8. I thought it would be 9 for obvious reasons. Is their something special going on in c# that I am failing to notice?

Comment: Welcome to Floating Point Numbers. Have fun tearing your hair out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PZRI1IfStY0

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/618596/9453080) will help you understand a little better. With `Single` (`float`) you'll only get an approximation (because the value is stored as a binary point type). You may want to change to `Decimal` (`decimal`) (stored as decimal point type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has to do with how float numbers are calculated and stored in binary. If you did `if ((3/10 - 2/10) == 1/10)` you would actually get `false` because the value the computer is getting is `3.0000000001`.

That happens because `1/10` can't be written in as a decimal binary. It's something like `0.0011` where the `0011` bit repeats forever.

It's similar to how `1/3` can't be rewitten as a decimal in our number system. We normally do `0.333333334`. This causes a lot of weird and annoying problems.

If you want more accurate numbers, use `decimal`. The decimal numbers are actually stored in base ten, not base 2, so that sort of stuff doesn't happen. Note that these are slower, however.